# Neo4j delete N relation

Tags: neo4j

There are 2 nodes

1. Posts
2. User

There is a relationship between 2 nodes called shared

```
(:User{name:'John'}) -[share:shared]-> (:Posts{name:'1'})
```

The user has shared news 5 times, so `count(share)` is 5. Now I need to remove 1 share. i.e. `count(share)` needs to be changed to 4.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that:

- your DB does not *literally* contain exactly 2 nodes (only 1 `User` node and 1 `Posts` node), and
- each `Posts` node only has a single incoming `shared` relationship

This is how you'd delete one `shared` relationship for 'John' if you don't care which post gets unshared (and you don't want to delete that post's node):

```
MATCH (:User {name:'John'})-[share:shared]->(:Posts)
WITH share LIMIT 1
DELETE share;
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to specifically delete the `shared` relationship between 'John' and the post with the `name` of '4' (assuming you don't want to delete that post's node):

```
MATCH (:User {name:'John'})-[share:shared]->(:Posts {name: '4'})
DELETE share;
```

Answer (score 0):

With something like that :

```
MATCH (:User{name:'John'}) -[share:shared]-> (:Posts{name:'1'})
WITH share LIMIT 1
DELETE share
```